# cgi.test() in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, post, cgi

Im currently learning to use [Google App Engine](http://www.appspot.com), and I modified [this example](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/handlingforms) to look like this:

```
import cgi
import webapp2

from google.appengine.api import users

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("""
          <html>
            <body>
              <form action="/sign" method="post">
                <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
                <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook"></div>
              </form>
            </body>
          </html>""")


class Guestbook(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        cgi.test()

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                              ('/sign', Guestbook)],
                              debug=True)
```

Because I wanted to see what does `cgi.test()` do. It produces output that matches the description in [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.2/library/cgi.html#cgi.test), but it incorrectly says there is no POST data. Additionally, it informs about the following error:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\cgi.py", line 918, in test
    print_environ(environ)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\cgi.py", line 944, in print_environ
    print "<DT>", escape(key), "<DD>", escape(environ[key])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\cgi.py", line 1035, in escape
    s = s.replace("&", "&amp;") # Must be done first!
AttributeError: 'LogsBuffer' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

This is on a localhost development environment. Why am I getting incorrect results? The example notes that not all Python functions are allowed though I doubt this would be the case with `cgi.test()`, would it?

edit: Do I have to change `app.yaml` in some way to allow for special treatment of `http://localhost:8080/sign`?

Comment: Don't mix CGI and WSGI. If your app is running in Python 2.7 as a multithreaded app, it's not a CGI app, even though the environment imitates some of those facets. If you have a main, it is a CGI app, but you're then using a WSGI wrapper which disguises that and will do things like reading standard input for you. Better to not break the abstraction and use only WSGI level environment

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Is there an equivalent of `cgi.test()` available in this environment?

Comment: Not really, no, but you could write your own fairly simply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the value of the wsgi.errors(and wsgi.input) is the actual instance:
For example it it some like this:

```
'wsgi.errors': <google.appengine.api.logservice.logservice.LogsBuffer object at 0x105219150>
```

and not its string representation and the escape method can only be called on a string.

**(Dirty hack)**
Find the file `google/appengine/runtime/request_environment.py` (i don't provide the full path since i don't know where your installation is located) and then at lines 111-112:

replace:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    return self._request.environ[key]
```

with:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    if key in ['wsgi.errors', 'wsgi.input']:
        return str(self._request.environ[key])
    return self._request.environ[key]
```

Comment: I used `if key.split('.')[0] == 'wsgi':` because there was more of this type, but it doesn't really fix my problem - which is that cgi.test() still reports no FORM fields (result here: http://pastebin.com/YiseAuQD), is there something similar to `cgi.test()` in WSGI environment?